# Concatenate predictions from two pre-trained Tensorflow models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, concatenation

I have 2 separate trained models that independently predict unrelated regression values from the same image. Both models use a pretrained VGG16 model as the base with specific top layers added.

When tested individually, both models perform well. When I concatenate the 2 pretrained models I get different predictions than running independently.

I declare the individual models as so:

```
# VGG
vggModel = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(310, 765, 3))
vggModel.trainable = True
trainableFlag = False

for layer in vggModel.layers:
    
    if layer.name == 'block5_conv1':
        trainableFlag = True
  
    layer.trainable = trainableFlag

# Model A
model_a = tf.keras.Sequential(name='model_a')
model_a.add(vggModel)
model_a.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model_a.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1))
model_a.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.01)))
model_a.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.01)))
model_a.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model_a.load_weights(model_a_wts)

# Model B
model_b = tf.keras.Sequential(name='model_b')
model_b.add(vggModel)
model_b.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model_b.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1))
model_b.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.01)))
model_b.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.01)))
model_b.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model_b.load_weights(model_b_wts)
```

And then I concatenate the models by:

```
common_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(310, 765, 3))

a_out = model_a(common_input)
b_out = model_b(common_input)

concatOut = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([a_out, b_out])

branched_model = tf.keras.Model(common_input, concatOut, name='Branched')
```

How is it possible to get different predictions in this scenario?

Comment: Two models are not independent as they share vggModel which is trainable. Replacing vggModel with tf.keras.models.clone_model(vggModel)  at model_b.add(vggModel) will work.

Comment: Yes, this worked! Can you make your comment into an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @hkyi 's comment the answer is:

The 2 models are not fully independent as they share vggModel (which is trainable). Therefore you need to clone the vggModel before adding it to model_b. Otherwise the weights loaded to model_b will overwrite the vggModel weights used in model_a.

Use tf.keras.models.clone_model(vggModel) instead:

```
# VGG
vggModel = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(310, 765, 3))
vggModel.trainable = True
trainableFlag = False

for layer in vggModel.layers:
    
    if layer.name == 'block5_conv1':
        trainableFlag = True
  
    layer.trainable = trainableFlag

# Model A
model_a = tf.keras.Sequential(name='model_a')
model_a.add(vggModel)
model_a.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model_a.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1))
model_a.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.01)))
model_a.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.01)))
model_a.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model_a.load_weights(model_a_wts)

# Model B
model_b = tf.keras.Sequential(name='model_b')
model_b.add(tf.keras.models.clone_model(vggModel))   <--- HERE IS THE CHANGE REQUIRED
model_b.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model_b.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1))
model_b.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.01)))
model_b.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.01)))
model_b.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model_b.load_weights(model_b_wts)
```